# C++ split string into array only using certain libraries

Tags: c++

I've been trying to look for solutions all over, but with no luck.

I have been able to read a text file to read in each row. Example:

```
1,001,-1999,Jun,12
2,001,-1999,Dec,05
3,001,-1999,Jun,01
```

Note that this text file has about ~12000 lines or so, so this is a very small sample. Now I am trying to store each string in between the commas into an array. I am only allowed to use iomanip, iostream, and string for the libraries. So no, I cannot use sstream, vector, fstream, or anything like that so please do not suggest it.

Below I wrote some code that I wrote as a quick test for a sample string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string tmp = "1,Mar,1998";
    string delimiter = ",";
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;

        while ((pos = tmp.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
            token = tmp.substr(0, pos);
            cout << token << endl;
            tmp.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        cout << tmp << endl;

}
```

My output is

```
1
Mar
1998
```

How would I then store these into an array? Would each element be counted as a separate string or are they all the same string, just with a new line?

Comment: is the number of tokens separated by a `,` fixed or it varies?

Comment: @Fureeish separated by `,`

Comment: that is not an answer to my comment. Regarding your input being `"1, Mar, 1998` I can see 3 tokens - `1`, `Mar` and `1998`. Is the number of tokens always **3** (or any other number) or different lines in your input file have different number of tokens?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Consider the following problems: 1) How to represent the contents of a single line from the input. 2) How to represent an array of those. 3) How to split the input into individual lines. 4) How to parse an individual line into the representation determined in step 1.

Comment: @Fureeish  Oh sorry. The number of tokens will always be a certain number.

Comment: Another problem is that even you cannot really tell what you are expecting. There are plenty of ways how you can store the `1`, `Mar` and `1998` into an array. You can use `char[]`,  `std::string[]` or even `char[][]`, however the last one is not recommended. It is unclear whether an array containing `'1', '\n', 'M', 'a', 'r', '\n', '1', '9', '9', '8'` satisfies your requirements

Comment: @Fureeish Since string can be used, it would make sense to stick with that. No point to make it even more complicated. Or if possible, make a struct to represent the record, with named fields, if that's allowed. Either way, there's a number of design choices to be made, and this really feels like a homework problem, so I'm reluctant to give any concrete solutions, but rather guide the OP to figure out as much themselves.

Comment: @DanMasek I am unwilling to provide any raw code for anyone who posts these kind of questions, however I am more than willing to help someone even with homework-kind questions, as long as they keep a quality expected here. Once an OP clarifies what is the expected output, it will be much easier to **guide** him/her.

Comment: I am not asking for any raw code, just ideas. I may try the struct idea though, thank you.

Comment: Nobody assumed that you asked for a raw code. We simply stated that it is unclear what the desired output is, and, if by any chance your quesion was mainly about **packing** your output into some sort of structure, not about splitting the input specifically, I apologise for misunderstanding. I highly encourage you to use a user defined `class` (or `struct`) containing as many `std::string`s as you would need for representing a single line

Comment: If you know there will be N items on each row and M rows then just create an array: `char*cells[N][M]` but if you don't know M and M ahead of time you will need to read the file twice: the first time to count and the second time to parse (creating the array between the two).  The advantage to that is that you will know if the file is valid before reading it into memory and potentially overrunning the array.

Comment: @Amy Are you allowed to hardcode the number of input records? If not, this might be even more tricky, since you'd have to handle resizing of the array as you parse the input. Basically reimplementing a subset of std::vector. If that's the case, it would make sense representing the record array as a class as well (the actual array being a member variable). ... to be honest, it wouldn't hurt to do that anyway -- separation of concerns.

Comment: @DanMašek looking at the text file again, and I don't think I can hardcode the number of inputs. Working on making a class for it though